# How do I express and solve this trivial logic puzzle?

Tags: prolog

I tried to express a more complex logic puzzle and boiled down where I'm failing at to this trivial problem:

- a `Car` can be `red` or `green` or `blue`
- `bmw` is not `red` and not `blue`
- *solution*: `bmw` is `green`

But how do I express this in Prolog? I'd assume there is an almost verbatim formulation, which is also my goal. Just stating the facts and rules and then query. I tried several different options. This would be one attempt:

```
is_(Car,Color) :- 
Color = red; 
Color = green; 
Color = blue.

is_(bmw,red) :- false. 
is_(bmw,blue) :- false.
```

But querying for `is_(bmw, C)` will yield all three colors instead of only `green`:

```
?- is_(bmw,C).
C = red ;
C = green ;
C = blue ;
false.
```

I sort of understand why this isn't working. But also sort of not.

Above pseudo solution itself is equivalent to:

```
f(X,a).
f(X,b).
f(X,c).
f(r,a) :- false.
f(r,b) :- false.
```

then:

```
?- f(r,X).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c ;
false.
```

I mean of course ... the facts are disjunctionally related (OR) hence f(r,a) can be true. Also above code without the irrelevant context of car colors makes it obvious that the "knowledge base" as-is is nonsense. But this just brings me back to - how to express it then correctly?

Could someone tell me how this would have to be done? And maybe infer from above pseudo-solution where my thinking is going wrong?

Comment: "a Car can be red or green or blue; bmw is not red and not blue" - solution: bmw is not a car...

Comment: I assume you intend to convey that this would be a possible solution given that I did not specify explicitly as a fact that bmw is a car.

Comment: Yes, tongue in cheek. I think you're looking for `\+` as the way forward, but it mildly annoys me to wrap such a small puzzle in 10 lines of code when it boils down to "take away some items from a list and show the remainder" e.g. `?- subtract([red, green, blue], [red, blue], Answer).`

Comment: well, my example is reduced to the most basic form. the puzzle I'm trying to solve has more entities and relations between them. then it's not so obvious anymore to represent it as a list operation and I'd like Prolog to do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in a relational database:

```
car_manu(bmw).

car_color_general(red).
car_color_general(green).
car_color_general(blue).

car_manu_not_color(bmw, red).
car_manu_not_color(bmw, blue).

car_manu_color(Manu, Color) :-
    car_manu(Manu),
    car_color_general(Color),
    % Ensuring that Manu and Color are instantiated, before using \+
    \+ car_manu_not_color(Manu, Color).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- car_manu_color(Manu, Color).
Manu = bmw,
Color = green ;
false.
```

Comment: well, it does make sense and of course `\+` is key here.

Comment: Instead of `f(X,a)` - which is about as vague as can possibly be - give everything *meaningful* names, and then (hopefully) the logic pretty-much writes itself.